# Error when creating a SQLite DB on Android (Code 1)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to create a simple database but I receive this error:

**09-09 12:42:14.750: E/AndroidRuntime(6971): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "values": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table values(_id integer primary key autoincrement, date text not null, screenTime integer not null );**

I tried to look at other similar questions without finding a solution although I suspect my create statement to be incorrect but I am not sure.
Below is my code.

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String TABLE_VALUES = "values";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date";
    public static final String COLUMN_SCREENTIME = "screenTime";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "screenTime.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database creation sql statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_VALUES
          + " ( " + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
          + COLUMN_DATE + " text not null, "
          + COLUMN_SCREENTIME + " integer not null );";

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
        "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_VALUES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VALUES is a [keyword](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

You could quote it, but it would be a better idea to use a different name.
(Note: "values" is pretty much meaningless; *every* table has values in it.)

Comment: I didn't knew that it is a keyword. Thanks for helping me out!